# Why is this very simple return std::move(thread handle) failing?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, move

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

thread&& launch(){
    thread launchee([](){
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(280));
        cout<<"HA!"<<endl;
    });
    return move(launchee);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    thread mine(launch());
    mine.join();
}
```

compiled with `g++-4.6 -std=c++0x 1.cpp -o e1 -pthread`

Outputs "terminate called without an active exception", then the program aborts.

This should work, shouldn't it??

Comment: rvalue references are still references. You don't want to return references to local variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to return a thread by value, not an *rvalue-reference*:

```
std::thread launch() {
    std::thread launchee([](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(280));
        std::cout<<"HA!"<<std::endl;
    });
    return launchee;
}
```

The reason is that `std::move` (and `std::forward`) are just a cast operation from an *lvalue* to an *rvalue-reference*, but unless you use that to actually *move* into some other object, the original object remains unmodified. In the original code you are then taking a reference to a local object and exiting the function, the `std::thread` inside the function is then destroyed and it calls `terminate` (as per contract of `std::thread`, for any other object it would just return a dangling reference to a destroyed object).

Comment: "but unless you use that to actually move into some other object".

But.. wasn't I?

Comment: @mako: No, you were using the cast to obtain a reference, but that reference is not being used (while the original object was still alive) as an argument to a move constructor/assignment. Consider this similar example: `void f() { type t; type&& lr = std::move(t); }` you perform the cast but you have not *moved* the object.

Comment: Misnamed `std::move` strikes again.